# display downloaded file without saving it on android?

Tags: android, download, android-contentprovider

I would to download a `.docx` file from internet  and display it with officesuite.Is it possible without saving downloaded file?(for example with content provider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on your HTTP `Uri`, also setting the MIME type, then call `startActivity()` on the `Intent`. If the user's device has an application which can not only view such files but also download them, it will handle the downloading for you. Whether those applications save the file, of course, is up to those applications.